# loading javascript libraries on pages with ajax calls to other pages

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page index.php that uses jquery and I have all the libraries loaded using the following code:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

On this page, I use an ajax call to pull a second page.  This second page has some jquery on it as well.  Do I need to have the script src links on the 2nd page as well as the first? or will the first page load the libraries and be fine?

I am getting an error when I pull the second page in via the ajax call.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'
```

Comment: Im sorry if the above is vague.  Stackoverflow quality control and I had a rough morning together :)

Comment: No, you don't need jQuery on the 2nd page as it's already loaded.  `dialog()` however, is from jQuery UI, so you'll need to include that in your first page as well :)

Comment: Thanks! i didnt realize i was missing ui.  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the jquery question, you don't need to put the library on second page

not sure about the type error, maybe post some of your code would help.

Comment: The above fixed this problem.